# Python: problem checking if first element of split line is a number

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a file and check if a line starts with a digit or not. My understanding is you can use `isdigit()` for that purpose. I have split my line, but I get a "list index out of range" error. That part of my code looks as follows:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    splitLine = line.strip().split()
    if(splitLine[0].isdigit()):
        #do something
```

What could be the reason? Ideally I'd also like to check if all elements of `splitLine` are digits. How can I best do that?

Comment: That's what happens when your line is empty. Throw an `if len(splitLine) == 0: continue` in or something. Or replace the `if` with a `for` loop so you can check everything.

Comment: `if splitline and splitLine[0].isdigit():`

Comment: `if splitLine[0:1].isdigit():`

Comment: Just a friendly heads up @desp_robin: If one of the answers helped you solve your problem, please click the checkmark button next to that answer to select it as the solution. This will help people who find the question in the future know right where to look. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `for loop`:

The `for split in splitline` will be skipped if the splitline is empty but will also check each element in splitline as OP said "Ideally I'd also like to check if all elements of splitLine are digits. How can I best do that?"

```
for line in f.readlines():
    splitline = line.strip().split()
    for split in splitline: #<-- Can check each element in splitline
        if split.isdigit():

            # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to split a line to check first element. it's first element is right there already. you only need to check that the line is not empty: `len(line)` gives you its size

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if len(line) and line[0].isdigit():
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters mentioned, the issue here is that `splitline` is empty, and trying to access *any* position in an empty list is an error.

You can fix this by first checking to see if your `splitline` list has any elements at all, like this:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    splitLine = line.strip().split()
    if splitline and splitLine[0].isdigit():
        do_stuff()
```

If `splitline` is empty, it will evaluate to `False`, so the attempt to access index 0 in an empty list will never happen.